# JQuery Mobile db success event not triggering function

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I am having a problem executing a success function within multiple success events, let me show you the code:

```
$("#beneficiarios").one("pagebeforeshow", function(){

    db.transaction( function(tx){ queryDBAll(tx, "Beneficiarios", 0, 10) }, onError ); //LOAD BENEFICIARIOS IN DB

    $("#btn-add-ben").click(function(){
        var nombres = $('#b_nombres').val();
        var apellidos = $('#b_apellidos').val();
        var dia = $('#b_dia').val();
        var mes = $('#b_mes').val();
        var año = $('#b_año').val();
        var fecha_nac = año+"-"+mes+"-"+dia;

        //ADD BENEFICIARIO TO DB
        db.transaction( function(tx){
            tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO Beneficiarios (nombres, apellidos, fecha_nac) VALUES ('"+nombres+"','"+apellidos+"','"+fecha_nac+"')",
            [],
            function(tx, results){
                var benid = results.insertId;
                $('#emptyBeneficiarios').remove();
                $('#ul-beneficiarios').append(
            '<li><a href="#" id="view_ben_'+benid+'">'+nombres+' '+apellidos+'</a><a href="#" id="del_ben_'+benid+'" data-position-to="window" data-icon="delete" class="itemDelete">Eliminar</a></li>').listview('refresh');
                $("#del_ben_"+benid).click(function(){
                    //PENDING: CONFIRM DIALOG
                    db.transaction( function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql("DELETE FROM Beneficiarios WHERE ID = "+benid),
                    [],
                    console.log(benid+" borrado con éxito!"),
                    onError
                    });
                });
                $("#view_ben_"+benid).click(function(){
                    db.transaction( function(tx){
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Beneficiarios WHERE ID = '+benid),
                    [],
                    //SUCCESS ACTION! -- NOT WORKING
                    function(tx, results) {
                        $('#b_nombres').val(results.rows.item.nombres);
                        $('#b_apellidos').val();
                        $('#b_dia').val();
                        $('#b_mes').val();
                        $('#b_año').val();
                        console.log(benid+" shown successfully!") //IS NOT SHOWN AT ALL
                    }
                    console.log(benid+" mostrado shown successfully without function!") //SHOWN AS DESIRED
                    ,
                    onError
                    });
                });
            },
            onError );
        },
        onError );
        });

    $( "#ul-beneficiarios" ).delegate( "li a", "click", function() {
        $(this).parent("li").remove();
        var li_num = $('#ul-beneficiarios li').length;
        if (li_num == 1) {
            addEmptyBeneficiarios('#ul-beneficiarios');
        }
        } );
});
```

As you can imagine I have an UL with LI that gets added when the ADD button is clicked, everything works fine, including the DB executions.

The problem is when I click the $("#view_ben_"+benid) it does run properly, but it doesn't execute the SELECT success function properly although it does show a the console.log set outside the success function. Anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out:
On the following line you are closing the `executeSql` function directly, leaving out the rest of the arguments unused in the function body. In other words: There's a bracket missing ;).

```
tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Beneficiarios WHERE ID = '+benid),
```

Change your syntax to the following example:

```
db.transaction( function(tx){
    tx.executeSql(
        ("DELETE FROM Beneficiarios WHERE ID = "+benid), // SQL COMMAND
        [],                                              // NO IDEA WHAT THAT IS FOR
        console.log("success"),                          // SUCCESS CALLBACK
        onError                                          // ERROR CALLBACK
    );
});
```

**I'd like to point out that you are cramming too many functions into each other. Consider outsourcing binding, success and error functions to the top level to prevent Inception like Matryoshka code.**